# Sklearn TruncatedSVD is not return n, components

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svd, latent-semantic-indexing

I fitting an LSA model on TfIdf matrix. My original matrix has

(20, 22096) then I'm applying TruncatedSVD to perform the LSI/Reduction

`svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=200, random_state=42, n_iter=10)
svdProfile = svd.fit_transform(profileLSAVectors)
print(np.shape(svdProfile))  #result (20, 20)`

instead of get (20,200) i'm getting (20, 20)

anyone has any idea about why ....?

Answer (score 2):

Its the "expected" behaviour in most decomposition procedures in Scikit-learn.

I cannot find this mentioned in documentation of TruncatedSVD, but you can see the [documentation for PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA), where its mentioned that:

```
n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)
```

You can try posting this on the [scikit-learn github issues](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues) page to get more clarity.

Comment: "Its the desired behaviour in most decomposition procedures" - can you please explain / refer a link to why this is? I'd like to know more.

Comment: @Raghuveer. Better word should be "expected" instead of "desired". I am sorry but I dont have any resources. Maybe you can look into the linked documentation for PCA above and go through the research papers linked there to get details.